# Importing a third-party css into an angular component

Tags: css, angular

I am working on an angular application (v14.0.0) in which the components use only plain CSS. I would like to import the styles of a third-party library that is currently in the node_modules folder, to a single component. That is because including the style file of the third-party library in angular.json results in overriding my custom styles. Though it would be possible to create an override, I am trying to avoid that as it will be a guessing game regarding the selectors that need to be overriden. I am not able to find any recommendations on how to effectively import the the styles into my component (from node_modules). I will appreciate any help.